# How can i show the image with data protocol in and android application

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I have a link to image that starts with data prorocol. I need to show image from that source in an android app. How can i achieve this?

[image: Snap of the image tag is given here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
Element image = doc.select("img[class=lr-logo-img lr-standings-logo-img").first();

String src = image.attr("src"); 
String key = ";base64,";    
int index = src.indexOf(key);
String base64 = src.substring(index+key.length());

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);       
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);     
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```